# How can I make it so that text.Split(' ')[0] increments?

Tags: c#

How can I make it so that text.Split(' ')[0] increments? I would like it to do text.Split(' ')[++] but putting that ++ in there doesn't work. The goal is to have the code count the "search" words. Sorry, new to c#.

```
using System;

namespace TESTER
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int wordCount = 0; 
            int index = 0;
            string text = "I ate a donut on national donut day and it tasted like a donut";
            string search = "donut";

            // skip whitespace until first word

            while (index < text.Length)
            {
                if (search == text.Split(' ')[0])
                {
                    wordCount++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(wordCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `text.Split(' ')[0]` returns a string. You cannot use `++` unless its a number

Comment: `.Split` returns an array, and an array has a `.Length` property. Are you asking how to iterate over an array?

Answer (score 4):

You could just do this:

```
string text = "I ate a donut on national donut day and it tasted like a donut";
string search = "donut";

int wordCount = text.Split(' ').Count(x => x == search);

Console.WriteLine(wordCount);
```

That gives `3`.

Comment: this does not seem to work in Visual Studio. It says count is not usable.

Comment: @Taylor `.Count` is a LINQ extension method. You need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.

Comment: The OP is clearly new to programming, LINQ is just going to confuse the OP...which it did.  Also, re-writing the OP's code entirely doesn't serve to help _where the OP went wrong_.  By not pointing out the original issue, the OP doesn't understand the mistake they made and so nothing is learnt from the exercise.  Remember _we are here for the OP_ not to demonstrate one's own cleverness.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this.

```
using System;

namespace TESTER
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int wordCount = 0; 
            int index = 0;
            string text = "I ate a donut on national donut day and it tasted like a donut";
            string search = "donut";

            // skip whitespace until first word

            string[] wordArray = text.Split(' ');
            while (index < wordArray.Length)
            {
                if (search == wordArray[index])
                {
                    wordCount++;
                }
            index++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(wordCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to cache `text.Split(' ')`'s result rather than keep re-splitting the string twice per iteration.

Comment: Ok, I'll make that change. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace TESTER
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "I ate a donut on national donut day and it tasted like a donut";
            string search = "donut";

            var wordCount = text.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Count(x => x == search);
            Console.WriteLine(wordCount);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want a case-insensitive search use:

```
var wordCount = text.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count(
     x => string.Equals(x, search, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer of Enigmativity is the right one. That's how you should do what you want.

But you're learning and using LINQ won't make it easier.

Your variable text is of string. When you use the *member* function `Split(...)` of the type `string` (or `String`, which is the same), it will return an `array of string`. This is `string[]`. To use the `[]` you can declare such an object.

```
string[] words;
```

Then you assign the result of your `text.Split(' ')` to it.

```
words = text.Split(' ');
```

This gives you access to all entries through the variable `words`.

```
string str = words[0];
```

To count without LINQ you can iterate through the array. Think this was you intention with the `[++]`. You have two options.

Use a for-loop or a foreach.

```
int wordCount = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < words.Count )
{
    if( words[i] == search)
        ++wordCount;
}
```

or the foreach-loop

```
// let pretend it's a real program here and
// reset the wordCount rather then declaring it
wordCount = 0;
foreach( string str in words )
{
    if( words[i] == search)
        ++wordCount;
}
```

Incrementation with the `++` sign, or it's opposite `--`:

These need a number. For instance an `int`.

```
int number = 0;
```

This you can increment with:

```
number++;
```

Now `number` will have the value of `1`.

You can use it in the indexer of an array. But you do need an integer.

Consider this code:

```
int index = 0;
while(index < words.Length)
{

    Console.WriteLine( words[ index++ ] );

}
```

Here you have the array `words`. In the indexer you request entry of what number holds as value. Then `index` will be incremented by `1` and due to the while-loop `index` will be 14 upon exiting the while-loop. 14 is the number of words in your initial string.